# I can't seem to print out a string from a structure but I can print an integer

Tags: c

My code is suppose to get the names of students and the student grade. After that I try to print the student names from the structure that I made and I can only get the grade to print. I get an error when trying to print the string using

```
printf("%s", test[0].names);
```

and the error says,

> Unhandled exception at 0x0fe113af (msvcr100d.dll) in StudentNamesAndGrades.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x65736f4a.

But when I use

```
printf("%d", test[0].studentScores);
```

It prints out the score of the first student. Here is the entire code because it might be something other than the way I'm trying to print it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

/*
    this program will get a name of students
    and then you will enter the grade for each one :)
*/

struct students
{
    char *names;
    int studentScores;
};


int main(void)
{
    int numStudents = 0;
    students *test;
    int i;

    printf("Enter the number of students in your class: ");
    scanf("%d", &numStudents);

    test = (students*)malloc(numStudents * sizeof(students));

    printf("Enter the names of the %d students\n", numStudents);

    for (i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of student %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", &test[i].names);
        printf("Enter the students score: ");
        scanf("%d", &test[i].studentScores);
    }

    printf("%d", test[0].studentScores);
    printf("%s", test[0].names);    // This is where I get a problem :/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this c++ or did you miss a `typedef`?

Comment: You missed to allocate memory for member of structure students  ie  char *names;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not allocate memory for `char *names;` while taking input at all.

Your struct could be like:

```
typedef struct students
{
    char names[30];
    int studentScores;
}students;
```

Also using `fgets` is safer than using scanf.

Comment: @John yes my answer clearly recommends using `fgets`

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for the `names` field, but I would recommend a different approach

```
struct students
{
    char names[100];
    int studentScores;
};
```

and then change the `scanf()` to

```
scanf("%99s", test[i].names);
```

there is another mistake in your first `scanf()` your are passing the address to the pointer, instead of the pointer.

You should use the address of `&` operator for the integer, because you need to pass a pointer to an integer for the `"%d"` specifier, but your `names` field variable was already a pointer, so no neet to take it's address.

Some other tips you might be interested in

1. Don't cast the result of `malloc`, although it seems that you are erroneously using a c++ compiler to compile c code, and in c++ you do need the cast, in c you don't, it makes your code harder to read and other problems which you can read with the most popular c question on Stack Overflow.
2. Check the return value from `malloc`, it doesn't matter how unlikely it could fail, since it could theoretically fail, you must check it's return value, which is `NULL` on failure.

Comment: 3. `scanf` is not buffer safe.

Comment: Yes I am using Visual Studio 2010 c++ compiler for C and that is the way that the zybooks website taught my class. Thanks for the response my code is fixed :)